# Tracing polyline between two points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, trace

How i can draw a line between two points...e.g.: I have initial point and endpoint 
and i need trace a line between this points...how i can do that?

Comment: Trace or Create? think the word trace is different - tracing is another function using a vector base map. Think the word 'create' is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a polyline feature class or a shapefile, load it into the map, start editing, turn snapping on, draw line from one point to the next, stop editing. Is this what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS 10 New Snapping:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_snapping/001t0000003t000000/

and Classic Snapping:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_the_editing_classic_snapping_environment/001t00000046000000/

Set your tolerances:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000040000000.htm

Classic Mapping:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000048000000.htm